# How to customize PowerShell continuation prompts?

Tags: powershell, prompt

I have been messing around with custom `prompt` functions in PowerShell. However, I cannot find a way to customize the continuation prompts.

By "continuation prompt", I mean the `>>` on the second line here:

[image: Continuation prompt]

Is that customizable at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the [PSReadLine module](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/psreadline).

```
PS C:\> (Get-PSReadLineOption).ContinuationPrompt
>> 
PS C:\> Set-PSReadLineOption -ContinuationPrompt '~~ '
PS C:\> @'
~~
```